# Convergence of $\sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\ln n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Convergence of $\displaystyle \sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\ln n}}$

How can we check the convergence of the given series . I tried a lot of series convergent tests ,but none of them seems to be  working,

Please provide me a hint , so that i can proceed it further.

Thank you.

Comment: hint: For $n> e^2$, $\log n>2$. Then, for such $n$'s we have $n^{\log n}> n^2$, that is $\frac{1}{n^{\log n}}<\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: Ignore first few terms and compare with $\sum \frac 1 {n^{2}}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy , this the main problem i'm facing, because for comparison test we have to show that $\forall n$, otherwise it is also working for $\sum \frac{1}{n^{1.5}}$ ,

Comment: @honeykumar: IThe comparison test only requires to compare terms  some integer $n_0$, so if $0\leq a_n\leq b_n$ for all $n\geq n_0$, if $\sum_nb_n$ converges, then so does $\sum_na_n$. If you want to use $\sum_m\frac{1}{n^{1000}}$ you can do that too.

Comment: Thankyou @JeanL. for your answer, hope someone will fix this mistake on Wikipidia,https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_series

Comment: What "mistake" are yo talking about?

Comment: @user10354138 if definition given by jean L. is right then there should be for all $n \geq n_{0}$ not  for all $n$

Comment: @honeykumar No.  Recall $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges iff $\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n$ converges.